# How insert a new line for each result of query select

Tags: php, html, mysql

I checked all the similar questions but I didn't find an answer.

I wanna insert a `<br/>` after each result of a query select but i can't do it, maybe because I use `float` property in CSS.

I'll explain my problem with code:

```
$sqlUser = "SELECT id,username FROM utenti where id IN (select idUtente from motopartecipanti where idItinerario = '".$idViaggio."') ORDER BY username";

$resultUser = $mysqli->query($sqlUser);

while($rowUser = $resultUser->fetch_assoc()) {

    $username = $rowUser["username"];
    $idUtente = $rowUser["id"];

    echo '
          <div style="float:left;">
              <label>'.$username.'</label>
          </div>
    ';

   $sqlTipo = "SELECT tipo FROM moto where id IN (select idMoto from 
    motopartecipanti where idItinerario = '".$idViaggio."' AND idUtente = 
    '".$idUtente."') ";

   $resultTipo = $mysqli->query($sqlTipo);

   while($rowTipo = $resultTipo->fetch_assoc()) {

      $tipo = $rowTipo["tipo"];

      echo '
            <div style="float:right;">
                <label>'.$tipo.'</label>
            </div>
     ';
   }
}
```

The code works but the output is:

```
Username1Username2                                     Type1Type2
```

Instead it should be:

```
Username1                                     Type1
Username2                                     Type2
```

*I used `mysql` tag too because maybe it can be a problem of query syntax*

Comment: @TorreSem is my answer working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a '' tag at the end of $tipo 'div' tag

```
while($rowTipo = $resultTipo->fetch_assoc()) {

  $tipo = $rowTipo["tipo"];

  echo '
        <div style="float:right;">
            <label>'.$tipo.'</label>
        </div><div style="clear:both">
 ';
}
```

Comment: it works but the second line has margin on the left and right

Comment: @TorreSem Can you check now. I would suggest using tables for simple formatting/styling like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can echo `<br/>`    tag or I think its better if you echo a **row** rather than `
. However this depends on your requirement.

```
 echo '
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <label>'.$tipo.'</label> <br/>
                </div>
         ';
```